# Change a link once Selenium web scraper is done and save as a different csv file, and keep going until there are no more additional links

Tags: python, selenium

I have a Selenium python web scraper that is currently set up to get one specific link. Here is the snip of the code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_path = r'//usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/81.0.4044.69/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,
                      chrome_options=options
                     )

driver.get(
"https://www.nytimes.com/search?dropmab=true&endDate=20100101&query=&sections=Business|nyt%3A%2F%2Fsection%2F0415b2b0-513a-5e78-80da-21ab770cb753&sort=best&startDate=20070101")
```

The scraper clicks a button on the page a few times and then scrapes all of the data, and saves it in a csv file.

How do I get the python file to change the link once the program is done running once and saving the csv file, and then run the program for that new link and save the file as a new csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to have a list of urls. We are going to iterate over that list of urls. We do not need to create a new browser for each url.

```
urls = ['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com']

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_path = r'//usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/81.0.4044.69/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,
                      chrome_options=options
                     )

for index, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
    #Web scraping code goes here
    with open(str(index+1) + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        #CSV writing code goes here


browser.quit()
```

CSV reading and writing examples can be seen here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! How can I have the csv filenames change as well? I don't want the same filename for every single one...that would cause files getting written over.

Comment: No problem. If you look at the first example for csv.writer, you can see the filename is represented as 'eggs.csv'. If you pass in your own variable, you can modify the name of the resulting csv file. Make sure to append .csv to the name

Comment: so this is how I have it set up right now

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFSLd.png

Comment: how can i change that?

Comment: Can I ask how you plan to name each individual file? What is your naming convention

Comment: I'm sorry can you please clarify the question? I'm really new to this and I'm still learning

Comment: No problem. So for url1.com what is your expected csv filename? For url2.com what is your expected filename? And so on. How will you determine the filename for each successive file you create?

Comment: So, it doesn't really matter as long as I am able to tell them apart. So for example url1.com would be <name>1.csv and url2.com would be <name>2.csv and so on and so forth

Comment: You would have to define that naming convention though. What is the value of <name>? So I need some idea of what to generate. Can I name them 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv?

Comment: yea that would be just fine

Comment: I have updated my answer with a potential solution.

Comment: with open(str(index+1) + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
NameError: name 'index' is not defined

Comment: I have added it to the for loop however

Comment: I have also modified my for statement, take a look at the line that starts the for loop as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211593/discussion-between-shubbbby-and-sri).